# OpenProject: How do I migrate my project from cloud version to my package installation?

Tags: migration

We have evaluated OpenProject and decided to install it in our office, and if we are happy, to upgrade to Enterprise.   However, I don't see any way to export migrate the projects that I created in myCompany.openProject.com, to my own installation.

The docs are clear about going from one package instance to another, but nothing on going from Openproject's hosted version, to one's own hosted instance.   Surely I don't need to retype all those work packages !   Please advise.  Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is answered in the [pricing FAQ on the website](https://www.openproject.org/pricing/).

> **Can I take my data from the hosted Cloud Edition to a self-hosted Community or Enterprise Edition?**
>   Yes. If you want to switch from a hosted version of OpenProject (Cloud Edition) to a self-hosted version (Community Edition or Enterprise Edition) we can provide you a full dump of your data. Since this requires manual effort for us, we will charge you € 120 for this service if you switch to the Community Edition. If you decide to switch to the Enterprise Edition, we import your data from the Cloud Edition for Free.

Comment: Thank you.   We will be upgrading to Enterprise but first I have to prove the value of OpenProject.   A chicken and egg problem.  I need the data today.

Comment: A clarification, what would help would be to knock the price of the  data migration off the enterprise edition, if we bought it within a certain time period; say six months or a year.

Comment: You should contact the sales team of OpenProject directly about that. Asking on a community platform is not going to get you any further.